# How to allow my visitors to arrange list items around via drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, css, html-lists

To make this a bit more simplified I will use an example as I can just implement the example into my live site.

Let's say I have a list of 5 items. (the list on my site is a bit more complex but I should have no problem implementing this to my site.)

```
<ol>
    <li>Apples</li>
    <li>Peaches</li>
    <li>Oranges</li>
    <li>Lemons</li>
    <li>Strawberries</li>
</ol>
```

Now for what ever reason the user wants Strawberries to be at the top of the list (#1) and for Peaches (#2) to be at the bottom of the list (#5). (Important to note: On the live site the users will be logged in and their preferences will be saved so that when they log back in those list items will be in their preferred order. The order they previously manually sorted them in. I will tackle that in another question though after this.)

How can I make it so that my visitor can drag and drop the list items into a specific order and or rearrange the list. (If there is a way of doing this that is not drag and drop that you feel is more efficient please let me know.)

Here is an example of something similar in the link below.

http://gridster.net/

In this grid they can drag and drop the boxes. I would like to do the same thing but in a list format. The items will be one on top of the other just like a normal list.

Comment: sortable is better for rearranging list items I think as you don't jsut want to drag and drop them but change the order in the markup

Comment: Yep, your prob right @RiaElliger, not sure why I didn't do this at the time (must of been a reason?) :)

Comment: I have many options for sorting my list items. But I need the ability to allow my users to put them in the EXACT order they want. Sorting is nice but it is limited as it executes the sort on all the items in the list. IE: My users may like the order that all the items are in except for just one item. He/she may want that item as the number one item or the last item with out effecting the order of any other list item.

Comment: did you even take a look at jQuery sortable before writing your comment? :-) It provides the possibiity to sort you items by drag and drop. EXACTLY what you asked for

Comment: @Ria, I did not. lol. =) Looked at it after I made the comment. I had no idea it existed. Figured you meant a regular sort. Sorry.

Comment: OK, fine ;) But yeah, it's really amazing. Did use it myself just a couple of days ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

You can export the selected order to json, save it where you want it to (database) and load it when the user comes back so the order will be the one that the user wants.

Comment: Oh that link you gave me is amazing. It also has the answers to a few questions I was gonna ask after this one was answered. Thanks so much for it! I will accept your answer.

Edit: I'm not exactly sure how you to do what you propose by exporting to json than save to DB. I'll make a different question for that though. Anyway, thanks for this answer!

Comment: no need for that. take a look at the methods. You can use toArray() and transform this array to json with standard JS